# Can a function that's undefined at a point be uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if a function such as $f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
      2+2x & \text{if}\ x>1 \\
      -2+2x & \text{if}\ x<1 \\
   \end{cases}$ can be uniformly continuous, as it's not defined at $x=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is uniformly continuous on the domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$, but $f$ is not continuous, or uniformly continuous, or even a function on any domain that includes $\{1\}$.